# Up-casting template argument types

Tags: java, upcasting

Why does Java not support automatic up-casting for template argument types?

For example, the following class will not compile unless the newly created `Derived` instance will be *manually* casted to a `Base` instance:

```
public class Example implements Iterable<Base> {

    @Override
    public Iterator<Base> iterator() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Derived()).iterator();
    }

    private class Base {
    }

    private class Derived extends Base {

    }
}
```

Comment: Return `Iterator<? extends Base>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to cast. 
The problem here is that `Arrays.asList(new Derived())` naturally tries to create a `List<Derived>`,
and then calling `.iterator()` on a `List<Derived>` naturally gives an `Iterator<Derived>`,
which is [not a sub-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p) of `Iterator<Base>`, so you get a compilation error.

You can specify that you want a `List<Derived>`, using `Arrays.<Base>asList`.
This works,
because you can certainly put a `Derived` instance into a `List<Base>`,
and then calling `.iterator()` on a `List<Base>` naturally gives an `Iterator<Base>`.

```
    class Example implements Iterable<Base> {
        @Override
        public Iterator<Base> iterator() {
            return Arrays.<Base>asList(new Derived()).iterator();
        }
    }
```